# Duplicated variable name in minified js file

Tags: javascript, minify

I had a issue in my recent deployment to prod. It is a .net project.

The issue is I have a line of code in one of my js file:

```
for(const work in worklist)
{
    ....
}
```

After the deployment, this js file got minified and the code was changed to

```
for(n in n)
{
}
```

I solved the issue by change the const to var. But it did take some time to figure this out and this is really a trouble that you only found this error after the prod deployment.

So I am wondering is there a way to test this in dev environment?
Is this a bug in the minify process or should I never use const? 
Is there a way to prevent this?

Thank you.

Ok, I had a another issue that I cannot solve like above. In another js file, a function:

```
$scope.a = function(ev){
   .....in the code here I am passing ev to another pop up window.      
}
```

got minified as:

```
t.a=function(t){
  ......now the ev passed to the pop up window is referring to $scope...
}
```

There is no way for me to rename $scope. If I rename ev to other variable name, it always got minified as t... Does anyone know how to solve this issue? This is so wired, I have never had this kind of minifed issue before.

The project is a .net mvc project, front end using angularJs. I think the project uses the default .net mvc minification.

Finally, I figure out a way to solve the issue. But I don't think this is a good solution. In that function, I have defined a inline controller. After I moved that controller out. The minification issue was solved. Any better solution is welcomed. Is there a way to test the minification js files in dev environment?

Comment: If worklist isn't used inside the loop you can safely name the loop variable the same name without any problem

Comment: @sebastian well ... if the `for..of` got transpiled to this, it has to access the values.

Comment: Stuff like this is why I stay with `worklist.forEach()` or `Object.entries( worklist ).forEach()`, so that there's an explicit scope for each iteration.

Comment: Depends on how you load the scripts. In `asp.net` we have an option that allows us to do that if we bundle our scripts in a config file.

Comment: Forgot to ask what env you're using? This way we can help find a way to minify them. To solve this issue like everyone else said check your scope.