# MVC minification seems to creating duplicate variable names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

This question seems to be more or less a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146536/asp-net-mvc-bundle-minficiation-duplicate-variable-name-conflict), but that one received no answers and is over 2 years old so I don't know what the protocol is ([I tried to find out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)).

Anyway, I've written an ASP.NET MVC5 web app and it all works fine in debug. After publishing to the server with the Release configuration I started seeing the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'n' before initialization".

After many hours of trawling through the code I think I've isolated the issue. I have this small function (it's a Knockout view model, but that's irrelevant):

```
eventIndexViewModel = function (params) {
    let self = this;

    // Map values from params object to properties of self
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
        self['_' + key] = value;
    }

    self.eventsView = ko.observable(self._eventsView);
    self.calendarToggleButtonClass = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.eventsView() === "calendar" ? "active" : "";
    });
    self.tableToggleButtonClass = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.eventsView() === "table" ? "active" : "";
    });
};
```

After being minified and published to the server, if I view the source in the dev tools console it looks like this:

```
eventIndexViewModel = function(n) {
    let t = this;
    for (const [n,i] of Object.entries(n))
        t["_" + n] = i;
    t.eventsView = ko.observable(t._eventsView);
    t.calendarToggleButtonClass = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return t.eventsView() === "calendar" ? "active" : ""
    });
    t.tableToggleButtonClass = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return t.eventsView() === "table" ? "active" : ""
    })
}
```

It is overkill to map the properties for the `params` object in this way in this particular instance, but I have much larger view models with many more properties in the same project and I want to keep them code consistent, so go with it.

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the minified version has renamed both the `params` variable *and* the `key` variable in the `for` statement to `n`, and I think that is what is causing my error. Certainly, that line with the `for` statement is where the error is thrown.

Am I understanding the cause of this problem correctly? If so, is it a bug in the minification process? And either way, how can I get around it?

Comment: Just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671821/duplicated-variable-name-in-minified-js-file) which is also essentially a duplicate but is also coming up on three years old with no accepted answer. However, it did put me onto the fact that if I replace `const [key, value]` with `var [key, value]` the minification changes it to `var [i,r]`, thus avoiding my variable name collision. Still, I'd be interested to know if there's a solution that doesn't involve me writing my code to accommodate the minification's bugs/quirks.